# Is carbon dioxide and water present in walls the reason for infrared not passing through walls?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I think this is a possibility because both water and carbon dioxide have a broad band of infrared absorption due to their molecular properties and as water may be present in the form of hydrated molecule or as water vapor on the surface and carbon dioxide also present on the surface as they are abundant in the atmosphere.

Comment: This is an interesting question! I'm willing to bet that even a film of paint stripped off of a wall and aggressively dried would not transmit infrared. Anyone have an IR camera?

Comment: Yes it could be, it depends a lot on the wavelength/frequency and the IR spectrum is quite broad and even gets divided usually in 3 or 5 subdivisions.
near infrared, NIR or IR-A: 0.75–1.4 micrometers (µm), commonly used in fiber optic telecommunications;
short wavelength IR, SWIR or IR-B: 1.4–3 µm (water absorption increases significantly at 1.45 µm);
mid wavelength IR, MWIR or IR-C: also called intermediate-IR (IIR), 3–8 µm
long wavelength IR, LWIR or IR-C: 8–15 µm;
far infrared FIR: 15–1,000 µm.
Keep in mind that people also often say the SWIR, MWIR and LWIR withouth the W.

Comment: but most of the band is absorbed by these molecules ,for carbon dioxide it is 12-19

Comment: @Confusedpal What I meant is that if you are using IR, you're device is probably only using a small part of the IR spectrum. Different IR camera's use different ranges of IR, so first figure out what part your camera uses ;)